# Smart Contract that can transfer ETH to other ETH Wallet (Owner of the Smart Contract)

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, ether, tokens, contract-debugging

I actually my partner created a Smart Contract which is able to create a new smart contract and send the proceeds. I'm quite new to Solidity unable to figure out a way to modify the smart contract to accept ETH from the sender, store it or send it directly to the Owner of the Smart Contract. Here's the code, help will be appreciated!

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

    contract EtherTransferTo {
    function () public payable {
    }

    function getBalance() public returns (uint) {
    return address(this).balance;
    }
}

    contract EtherTransferFrom {

    EtherTransferTo private _instance;

    function EtherTransferFrom() public {
    // _instance = EtherTransferTo(address(this));
    _instance = new EtherTransferTo();
   }

    function getBalance() public returns (uint) {
    return address(this).balance;
    }

    function getBalanceOfInstance() public returns (uint) {
    //return address(_instance).balance;
    return _instance.getBalance();
    }

    function () public payable {
    //msg.sender.send(msg.value);
    address(_instance).send(msg.value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a contract which simply forwards any ETH to the contract owner, you will need to:

- Define an owner of the contract on contract creation
- Create a payable function on the contract
- Have that payable function forward the funds to that owner

Here is a really simple sample to get started (untested and not ready for production):

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract EthForward {
    address _owner;

    constructor() public {
        _owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function() public payable {
        _owner.transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

This contract takes advantage of two key concepts:

1. The [constructor function](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html#creating-contracts)
2. The [fallback function](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html#fallback-function)

You should spend time learning more about solidity through [official documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/index.html) and tutorials like [Cryptozombies](https://cryptozombies.io/)

Comment: I have tested the code and it's working fine. Thanks for the suggestion. Can a smart contract accept ETH and send the same number of tokens as of ETH sent plus send the ETH to the owner?

Comment: Sure, that just requires you to use a token interface (erc-20 most likely), and to write a function to add tokens to a user when they make a payment. Again, I recommend you start in a more theoretical way, and learn solidity as a language, and then take your knowledge and apply it to a specific problem you want to solve.